# Merge data when each observation identified across TWO variables

Tags: merge, stata, data-wrangling

My data in Stata looks like this

| Cluster | Household |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |

So, each observation does not have a unique identifier that is one variable. The unique identifier is spread across TWO variables - "cluster" and "household". How can I merge multiple files with this type of identifier?

I am thinking I need to generate a new variable that references cluster and household, and repeat this across the multiple files. Then, I can use this newly generated variable as the identifier to merge the files.

Can you guide me through this?

I don't think an m:m merge is the solution because not all of the files contain the same households. In some files, some households are missing.

Comment: You can `merge` on a _varlist_, namely one or more identifier variables. See the manual entry for examples. The first I found  `merge`s on identifier and time, which is common in panel data. but there is nothing odd about two variables jointly identifying as in your case.  It still sounds like 1:1 `merge`s.

Comment: Gotcha. I see that now, but I have a new problem. One file is uniquely identified by "cluster" and "household" and a second file has multiple observations for some households because they surveyed multiple women in the same household. So, if I try to merge the two files using "merge 1:1 var1 var2 using filename" I get "variables var1 var2 do not uniquely identify observations in the using data" Do you have suggestions?

Comment: That is a different question and you should start a new thread OR edit this one with data examples. Serious questions can't be answered well in comments.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a file called `file1` that matches this description:

> One file is uniquely identified by "cluster" and "household"

and a second called `file2` what matches this description:

> a second file has multiple observations for some households because they surveyed multiple women in the same household.

then you need a `1:m` merge:

```
use file1

merge 1:m cluster household using file2
```